# Can't start server on PostgreSQL 11.17 - WSL

Tags: postgresql-11

I have postgresql-11.17 source code on my windows, followed the installation from the documentation : [PostgreSQL-11 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/install-short.html) but when I run the command  `./pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l logfile start` it shows the error :

```
waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: logfile: Permission denied
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

I had it running fine a few times previously, but now it does not work. I think it is because there are some processes running still, but I don't know the commands to kill them on WSL neither what are their names.

Comment: I faced similar issue and this solution works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60291060/10715658

Answer (score 0):

So, one way I found that solves the problem is doing a `sudo top` and then killing the postgres processes with `k` , give the PID you want to terminate and then `SIGKILL` command (9).

Comment: Also, when finished working with the database, do a ```./pg_ctl -D /path/to/bin/data -l logfile stop``` so that you don't come up with this kind of problem later